# Is there non real number of x that sufficient for this $11-\sqrt 7 x = 4x - 10$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Is there non real number of x that sufficient for $11-\sqrt 7 x = 4x - 10$ and $|\sqrt 7 x - 11 | = 4x - 10$

There is a solution which is real number.

Comment: This is a strange question. If $x$ is complex in the second equation, the module is real so $4x-10$ is real, so $x$ is real. No pure imaginary solution.

Comment: Do you mean $(\sqrt 7)x$ or $\sqrt{(7x)}$?  I have to assume that latter (the former is obvious) but you wrote the former.

Comment: @fleablood: Even in that case, isn't the result still real?

Comment: Yeah... i guess so.  If we ignore the absolute value criterion and allowed for $\sqrt{complex}$ numbers I wasn't 100% sure $11 - \sqrt{7x} = 4x -10$ had strictly real solutions.  But it does.

Comment: Complex numbers add extra  options but they are not magic.  If an equation has solutions it has solutions.  Jumping from real to complex aren't going to change things.  (And as $u=\sqrt x$ so $11-\sqrt 7u = 4u^2 -10$ will have two solutions (which are both real; but we can't accept the negative one) at most considering complex vs. real won't change the solutions.

Answer (score 1):

The only solution to $11-\sqrt 7 x = 4x - 10$ is $x=\dfrac{21}{4+\sqrt{7}}$.

It is a real number, about $3.16$

It also satisfies $|\sqrt 7 x - 11 | = 4x - 10$

Comment: I have to suspect the OP meant $\sqrt{(7x)}$ and not $(\sqrt 7)x$ even though that is what s/he wrote.

Comment: @fleablood suggest you put an answer with that in mind, beginning "In case you actually intended this..."

Comment: I'm working on it.

Comment: @fleablood, why does it matter? The module on the second equation is real so $4x-10$ is real, so $x$ is real either way...

Comment: Yeah.... Atticus.  You are correct.  Still..... not sure what the OP is going for.

Comment: Even is we ignore the module requirement it is still only real.

Answer (score 1):

Hint. Solve the first equation for $x$. The only answer is real. Then check whether that value of $x$ satisfies the second equation.

Complex numbers don't come into play at all.

Answer (score 1):

$|anything|$ is always a positive real number.

So $|anything| = 4x - 10$ will only have real solutions (if any solutions at all).

Also for complex numbers, $x$ we tend not to use the notation  $\sqrt{x}$ as it is ambiguous.

I'm going to assume you meant $\sqrt{7x}$ (which is the square root of $7x$) and not $\sqrt{7}x$ (which is $x$ times $\sqrt 7$)

$11 - \sqrt{7x} = 4x -10$

$4x + \sqrt 7\sqrt x -21 = 0$

$\sqrt{x} =\frac {-\sqrt 7 \pm \sqrt{7+4*21*4}}8=$

$\frac {-\sqrt 7\pm \sqrt {342}}8$

Note:  $\frac {-\sqrt 7- \sqrt {342}}8$ is negative while $\frac {-\sqrt 7+ \sqrt {342}}8$ is positive.  But both are *real*.

Even if we use $\sqrt{x}$ to allow for other than non-negative real numbers and to apply for any $k$ so that $k^2 = x$ (which is *not* what we do... at least not for real number-- and if we use complex numbers we avoid the notation $\sqrt{}$ altogether:  but for the sake of being thourough, I will pretend we can allow $\sqrt x < 0$.... which we really can *not* do....) we will nave

$x = (\frac {-\sqrt 7\pm \sqrt {342}}8)^2$ which can only be a positive real number.

Now if we have $|11-\sqrt{7x}|\ne 11- \sqrt{7x}$ and as $11-\sqrt{7x}$ is real mus mean $|11-\sqrt{7x}| = \sqrt{7x} - 11 = 4x-10 = 11-\sqrt{7x}$ which is impossible.

So $x = (\frac {-\sqrt 7\pm \sqrt {342}}8)^2$.

*BUT* as we *DON'T* define $\sqrt{x}$ as *any* $k$ so that $k^2 =x$ but *only* as the *non-negative* real $k$ so that $k^2 = x$ we have

$x= (\frac {-\sqrt 7+ \sqrt {342}}8)^2$ is the only real solution.

Comment: Your answer is often long and lot of explanations. Seems you enjoyed.